Jupyter notebook kernel is not connecting to correct python environment
Version: jupyter_client   : 8.6.2
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.2
jupyterlab       : 4.2.3
Here are steps I've took to create kernel in my jupyter notebook.

Create conda env: conda create --name firstEnv

conda env list correctly show firstEnv and it is located /Users/username/miniforge3/envs/firstEnv

add environment to kernel
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user --name firstEnv --display-name firstEnv

now this environment is correctly shown on top right of jupyternotebook where you can change your kernels.


But problem is python path from
conda activate firstEnv > which python from command line shows /Users/username/miniforge3/envs/und_me/bin/pip which is different from what I get from jupyter notebook. In jupyter notebook with correct kernel, running print(sys.executable) shows /Users/username/miniforge3/bin/python
I've followed many resources which seemed to do exactly what I've done above. Any clue to why I am facing this issue?

Just to make sure, did you run conda activate firstEnv between 1 and 2 and did you make sure that python -m ipykernel actually called the python interpreter from firstEnv?

@FlyingTeller Yup that was it... Thanks!
